# Extending the Bluetooth transmission distance of android smartphone

Tags: android, bluetooth, smartphone

I am looking for ways to extend the Bluetooth data transmission distance.

Android seems to support only TX power about BLE, not classic BT.

- To upgrade the built-in antenna by disassembling the smartphone.
- Using Linux layer(Bluetooth driver, etc) manipulations/commands.

Both seem quite difficult, please advise on this or suggest another way.
It doesn't have to be a programmatic way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Use hardware that supports Bluetooth Coded Phy (aka: BLE Long Range). https://stackoverflow.com/q/57681479/7721752

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.